# NewsLetter en Prontus

Tags: php

Buenas a todos

Tengo una situación con una página web en **Prontus**, lo que pasa es que hay una sección para suscribirse al Newsletter, pero el código aparentemente no funciona, para hacer la verificación de que enviaba información a la base de datos, lo que se quiere hacer es que el contenido del formulario lo envíe también a un correo electrónico. **Por qué toca verificar así y no mirar directamente la base de datos?** Porque no tengo acceso a la base de datos.

**Sitio web:** [www.conchali.cl](http://www.conchali.cl)

**Código:**

***CODIGO HTML***

```html
<div id="form-main">
  <div id="form-div">
    <form class="form" id="form1" method="post" action="guardar.php">
      <div class="head">  
          <img class="env" src="/site/imag/global/envelope.png" width="90px" alt="">
        </div>
         <h2 class="tit">Suscríbete a nuestro boletín<br> informativo aquí</h2>
           <p class="par">Recibirás todos los panoramas y actividades de Conchalí.</p>
      <p class="name">
        <input name="name" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[onlyLetter],length[0,100]] feedback-input" placeholder="Ingresa tu nombre" id="name" />
      </p>
      
      <p class="email">
        <input name="email" type="text" class="validate[required,custom[email]] feedback-input" id="email" placeholder="Ingresa tu email" />
      </p>
     <div class="submit">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="ENVIAR" id="button-blue"/>
        <div class="ease"></div>
     </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</div>
```

***CODIGO PHP***

```html
<?php
$db_host='localhost';
$db_user='name';
$db_email='email';
$db_name='mailing';
$$db_table_name='suscriptores';
$db_connection = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_email);

if (!$db_connection) {
    die('Gracias!, pronto recibirás información de nuestras actividades');
}
$subs_name = utf8_decode($_POST['name']);
$subs_email = utf8_decode($_POST['email']);

$resultado=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$db_table_name." WHERE Email = '".$subs_email."'", $db_connection);

if (mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0)
{

header('Location: Fail.html');

}else{
    
 $insert_value = 'INSERT INTO `' . $db_name . '`.`'.$db_table_name.'` (`Name`,`Email`) VALUES ("' . $subs_name . '", "' . $subs_last . '", "' . $subs_email . '")';

mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_connection);
$retry_value = mysql_query($insert_value, $db_connection);

if (!$retry_value) {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
    
header('Location: Success.html');
}

mysql_close($db_connection);
        
?>
```

Ese es el código que originalmente estaba en la página, y el que se quiere verificar si esta enviando información correctamente.

Lo reemplacé por este código para que no guarde en la base de datos sino que directamente envíe a al correo electrónico.

***Código***

```html
<?php
$subs_name = utf8_decode($_POST['name']); //**Recoge datos del campo Nombre
$subs_email = utf8_decode($_POST['email']); //**Recoge datos del campo email

$mail = "Nombre: " . $subs_name . "\n" . "Correo: " . $subs_email . "\n" . "Enviado desde pagina de conchali";

//Titulo
$titulo = "Suscribción nueva - Conchali";

//cabecera
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 

//dirección del remitente 
$headers .= "From: Web Conchali < ejemplo@email.com >\r\n";

//Enviamos el mensaje a tu_dirección_email 
$bool = mail("ejemplo@email.com",$titulo,$mail,$headers);
if($bool){
    echo "Mensaje enviado";
}else{
    echo "Mensaje no enviado";
}
?>
```

Pero no envía ninguna información, podrían ayudarme? Y de que manera se pueden unir los dos códigos **PHP**? Para que guarde en la base de datos y envíe también al correo electrónico.

Muchas Gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Respecto del envío de correo verifica si el servidor web en el cual estas trabajando, tiene el módulo de envío de correo, y más importante aun asociado un servidor mail (debes verificar la config de php).

respecto de la segunda pregunta debes verificar agrupar ambos procesos, lo más lógico es siempre primero guardar en BD, para luego enviar el mail al usuario por tanto, lo más rápido es secuencial.

```
<?php
$db_host='localhost';
$db_user='name';
$db_email='email';
$db_name='mailing';
$db_table_name='suscriptores';
$db_connection = mysql_connect($db_host,$db_user,$db_email);

if (!$db_connection) {
die('Gracias!, pronto recibirás información de nuestras actividades');
}
$subs_name = utf8_decode($_POST['name']);
$subs_email = utf8_decode($_POST['email']);

$resultado=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ".$db_table_name." WHERE Email =     '".$subs_email."'", $db_connection);

if (mysql_num_rows($resultado)>0)
{

header('Location: Fail.html');

}else{

  $insert_value = 'INSERT INTO `' . $db_name . '`.`'.$db_table_name.'` (`Name`,`Email`) VALUES ("' . $subs_name . '", "' . $subs_last . '", "' .     $subs_email . '")';

mysql_select_db($db_name, $db_connection);
$retry_value = mysql_query($insert_value, $db_connection);

   if (!$retry_value) {
   die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}

    header('Location: Success.html');
 }

mysql_close($db_connection);


 $mail = "Nombre: " . $subs_name . "\n" . "Correo: " . $subs_email . "\n" . "Enviado desde pagina de conchali";

 //Titulo
  $titulo = "Suscribción nueva - Conchali";

 //cabecera
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
 $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n"; 

//dirección del remitente 
$headers .= "From: Web Conchali < ejemplo@email.com >\r\n";

//Enviamos el mensaje a tu_dirección_email 
$bool = mail("ejemplo@email.com",$titulo,$mail,$headers);
  if($bool){
echo "Mensaje enviado";
 }else{
   echo "Mensaje no enviado";
  }


  ?>
```